# Exact match using application.match

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim J As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim a As Worksheet
Dim b As Worksheet
Set a = Workbooks("500 PRO").Worksheets(1)
Set b = ActiveSheet
LastRow = a.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(a.Cells(i, 2).Value, b.Columns(2), 0)) Then
        Set FindRow = b.Columns(2).Find(a.Cells(i, 2))
            J = FindRow.Row

        If IsEmpty(b.Cells(J, 6)) = True Then
            b.Cells(J, 6).Value = a.Cells(i, 10).Value
        End If

        If IsEmpty(b.Cells(J, 7)) = True Then
            b.Cells(J, 7).Value = a.Cells(i, 14).Value
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Unfortunately using application match is only looking at the first numbers in a column, rather than the full figure.

I tried something like:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Find(a.Cells(i, 2).Value, b.Columns(2), 0)) Then
```

but it falls foul of the same problem.

The code is comparing values in two worksheets, a and b. These are ID numbers. If two ID numbers match, it checks if two values on the first worksheet are blank, if they are, then the missing values are taken from the second worksheet.

Comment: How about a written explanation of exactly what you are trying to do, along with a sample of your data and expected output.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've updated the post with an explanation of what it is supposed to do

Comment: there are some extra arguments with find that you can add, to check `xlWhole` rather than `xlPart`

Comment: Just use the `Range.Find` method (with its various arguments) to see if the ID in `a` is in `b`.  No need for `Match` at all.  Also, I suggest you declare all your variables (set Option Explicit at the beginning; and in Tools/Options/General set Require Variable Declaration).

Comment: I changed it to `If b.Columns(2).Find(a.Cells(i, 2), lookat:=xlWhole) Then` and I am getting the error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set, on that specific line.

Comment: See my answer.  Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: In particular, with regard to the syntax in your comment, `Range.Find` returns a **Range Object** (or nothing) and you are checking it as a **Boolean**.  Proper syntax for your `If` might be `If Not b.Columns(2).Find(a.Cells(i, 2), lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then ` but I think the method in my answer might be more clear and simpler.

Comment: That did it. Simply changing it to `IF Not` and `Is Nothing` solved all the problems. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be certain because you did not provide sample data to use, but to use `Range.Find` successfully, try something like the following:

```
Dim foundCell As Range

With b.Columns(2)
  For i = 2 To LastRow
    If a.Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
        Set foundCell = .Find(what:=a.Cells(i, 2), _
                                lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
            If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
                '...
                'check for blanks and copy
                '...
            End If
    End If
  Next i
End With
```